# Microsoft Speech API Error : .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" '

Tags: codeblocks, sapi

I have a problem with SAPI: While I am compiling some code, I encounter this error in CodeBlocks:

```
 ||Warning: .drectve `/DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" /DEFAULTLIB:"uuid.lib" ' unrecognized|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Documents and Settings\Mert\Desktop\yazi\okuproje\main.c|11|undefined reference to `CoInitialize@4'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Mert\Desktop\yazi\okuproje\main.c|14|undefined reference to `CoCreateInstance@20'|
C:\Documents and Settings\Mert\Desktop\yazi\okuproje\main.c|29|undefined reference to `CoUninitialize@0'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

My Code: http://pastebin.com/LCpCns2p

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which compiler you're using with CodeBlocks (or, more importantly, which linker), however, the errors you're getting are caused by missing libraries.

You'll need to add a reference to `uuid.lib` (to get the GUID definitions for `IID_ISpVoice`), and `ole32.lib` (to get the definitions for `CoInitialize`, `CoCreateInstance`, and `CoUninitialize`).